# Python 3.5 to compute the average of the first 100 odd numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I compute the average of the first 100 odd numbers using the below code?

```
    i=1
    for i in range(100):
        a= i+2
    b=a/i
    print(b)
    print(a)
    print(i)
```

Where i is the initial number,
b= sum of the first 100 odd numbers
a is the average of the first 100 odd numbers.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've amended it with the actual question.

Comment: Actually it's a simple calculation you can do in your head when you notice that there are 50 pairs of 200.

Comment: Do you mean the first 100 odd numbers, or do you mean the odd numbers included in the range 0 to 99?  It's not clear what you mean by "using the code below" because of the inconsistency between your question and your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function from the statistics module, built in to Python 3. You can generate a sequence of odd numbers using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
>>> list(range(1, 200, 2))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99, 101, 103, 105, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115, 117, 119, 121, 123, 125, 127, 129, 131, 133, 135, 137, 139, 141, 143, 145, 147, 149, 151, 153, 155, 157, 159, 161, 163, 165, 167, 169, 171, 173, 175, 177, 179, 181, 183, 185, 187, 189, 191, 193, 195, 197, 199]
```

Then,

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> print(mean(range(1, 200, 2)))
100
```

If you are not able to use `statistics.mean()` you can combine `range()`, `sum()` and `len()`:

```
>>> odd = range(1, 200, 2)
>>> print(sum(odd) / len(odd))
100.0
```

And here's a way to do it using just `range()`:

```
total = 0
length = 0
for i in range(1, 200, 2):
    total += i
    length += 1

print(total / length)
# 100.0
```

If you can't use range():

```
n = 199
total = 0
length = 0
while n > 0:
    total += n
    length += 1
    n -= 2

print(total / length)
```

Comment: How can I do so with the original code above, without making use of the statistics package?

Comment: Use the range function

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
i=1
total=0
count=0
for i in range(100):
    if i%2 != 0:
        total=total+i
        count=count+1
average=total/count
print 'total %d' % (total)
print 'count %d' % (count)
print 'average %d' % (average)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a 1 byte long

Average sum of first n odd numbers is n

```
1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2n+1 = n^2
```

Therefore the average is just `n^2/n = n`

In your case the answer is 100.

In terms of code

`def avgOfFirsrtNOdd(n): return n`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

```
sum([i for i in range(1,200,2)])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [1]: b = sum(range(1,100,2))

In [2]: a = b/len(range(1,100,2))

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 2500

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 50
```

b = sum of the first 100 odd numbers 
a = average of the first 100 odd numbers